# Create a Security Group on Openstack for Cloud Foundry

Tags: security, openstack, cloud-foundry, rackspace, usergroups

I have a couple of questions. I am using Rackspace for Infrastructure which as I'm sure most of you know sits on top of Openstack. My question is how can I create security groups in an infrastructure where a tool for it doesn't exist? I am having trouble finding much information on this on the web.

Correct me if I'm wrong but a security group is basically a way of assigning different IP Tables to different groups on the system, right?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

## Dome9

Depending on your needs, one solution to set up security groups might be [Dome9](https://cloudtools.rackspace.com/apps/485?1801643525#overview).

Here is a blog post that walks through the process of setting up Dome9 with Rackspace:
http://www.rackspace.com/blog/cloud-security-create-security-groups-for-your-rackspace-servers/

## OpenStack Security Group

If you want to do it yourself, you might have a look at the OpenStack Security Group [Overview](http://docs.openstack.org/network-admin/admin/content/securitygroups.html) and [API](http://docs.openstack.org/network-admin/admin/content/securitygroup_api_abstractions.html).